# what is the order of source operands in AT&T syntax compared to Intel syntax?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, att

The Intel ISA reference documentation for this instruction is clear:

```
VPBLENDVB xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/m128, xmm4
```

> Select byte values from `xmm2` and `xmm3/m128` using mask bits in the specified mask register, `xmm4`, and store the values into `xmm1`.
>
> `xmm1` is the destination, `xmm2/3/4` are source operands

So what does this become using AT&T syntax? We know that the destination register must be last, but what is the order of source operands?

```
vpblendvb $xmm2, $xmm3, $xmm4, $xmm1
```

or

```
vpblendvb $xmm4, $xmm3, $xmm2, $xmm1
```

or something else?

Comment: The fastest way to find out is to check - use an Intel syntax assembler in combination with an AT&T syntax disassembler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assembling (note GAS uses `%` instead of `$` to denote registers) the following:

```
vpblendvb %xmm4, %xmm3, %xmm2, %xmm1
```

with the GNU assembler (version 2.21.0.20110327 on x86_64 2.6.38 linux) and then disassembling yields:

```
$ objdump -d a.out
    0:    c4 e3 69 4c cb 40     vpblendvb %xmm4,%xmm3,%xmm2,%xmm1
```

in intel syntax (as the manual shows):

```
$ objdump -d -M intel a.out
    0:    c4 e3 69 4c cb 40     vpblendvb xmm1,xmm2,xmm3,xmm4
```

So it looks like the order of all the arguments is reversed.

Comment: Yes, always just reverse the list vs. the Intel syntax order from CPU manuals.