# What does the x86 line "imulq $44,(%rbx), %rax" do?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I understand that imul is signed multiplication, and the documentation seems to suggest that the three operand syntax is `imulq dest, source1, source2`. Therefore the line would read as: Multiply the contents of the address stored in %rbx and the value in %rax, then store it in memory location 44, but this surely isn't correct?

Comment: You're getting confused between Intel syntax and AT&T syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the order of source operands in AT&T syntax compared to Intel syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548509/what-is-the-order-of-source-operands-in-att-syntax-compared-to-intel-syntax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the three-operand variant of the `imul` instruction, which is defined in the instruction set reference as `IMUL r64, r/m64, imm8` and means "Multiply the contents of `r/m64` by `imm8` and store the result in `r64`". There is also another variant of this instruction, which takes a 32-bit immediate, but it is impossible to tell which variant will be actually emitted by the assembler in this case.

Now, your assembler seems to be using the AT&T syntax of x86 assembly. It is used by the GNU assembler by default. It is known for specifying the operands of the instruction in reverse order. Thus, `imulq $44, (%rbx), %rax` will multiply the contents of the memory at address stored in `%rbx` by `44`, and store the result in `%rax`.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the order of the operands differently to how the documentation describes it.

It reads as: "Get the signed integer value stored in the memory address in register rbx, multiply it by 44, and put the result in register rax."

Or simply:
`imulq multiplier1, multiplier2, destination`

Comment: It is actually `imulq multiplier2, multiplier1, destination`. The parameters are all reversed in AT&T syntax. When you look at Intel's documentation, you need to reverse what they say. (Not that it matters in this particular case, of course, since multiplication is commutative.)